# Slow performance drawing dashed lines in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas

I am attempting to make a Pong clone using HTML5 canvas. I want to draw a dashed line down the middle of the playing field as is found in the original Pong. I am doing this by extending the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` object as shown in [David Geary's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132761610) excellent book:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.dashedLine = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, dashLength) {
    dashLength = dashLength === undefined ? 5 : dashLength;

    var deltaX = x2 - x1;
    var deltaY = y2 - y1;
    var numDashes = Math.floor(
              Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) / dashLength);

    for (var i=0; i < numDashes; ++i) {
        context[ i % 2 === 0 ? 'moveTo' : 'lineTo' ]
         (x1 + (deltaX / numDashes) * i, y1 + (deltaY / numDashes) * i);
    }
```

I then have a `render()` function that actually makes all the calls to render elements on the canvas. Included in this is my `renderBackground()` function which colors the background and draws the dashed line:

```
function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    renderBackground();
    // Rest removed for brevity
}

function renderBackground() {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    ctx.dashedLine(0, 0, 0, cHeight, 10);
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

Then at the end I have a function called `animLoop()` that actually calls the `render()` function and makes use of `requestAnimationFrame()` for smoother animations:

```
function animLoop() {
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return (
           window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           function( callback ){
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           }
        );
})();
```

If I let my game run for more than 30 seconds it starts slowing down dramatically to the point that it is unplayable and CPU usage by the browser hovers around 134% for both Firefox and Chrome. The slowness is only present when I am rendering the dashed line. I am not sure what is going, but below I also ran my code through Chrome Inspectors profiler and get the following:

[image]

My `renderBackground()` function is only taking .46% of the CPU time. Also I am not sure what the `(program)` is supposed to signify. Any thoughts on what could be causing the slowness?

Also you can see the complete code I have so far on my [Github repo](https://github.com/nryoung/pong.js).

Comment: Looks like you are accumulating all calls of lineTo on the default path. Try put `ctx.beginPath()` before `ctx.dashedLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accumulating all calls of lineTo on the default path each time `ctx.dashedLine` is called and call stroke will stroke all lines in path since the application start. Because you are running an animation, quickly the path will have a LOT of lines to draw when stroke is called each frame.

Add `ctx.beginPath()` before `ctx.dashedLine` to solve the problem.

```
function renderBackground() {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    ctx.beginPath(); // <-- add it here 
    ctx.dashedLine(0, 0, 0, cHeight, 10);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

When drawing using a path, you are using a virtual "pen" or "pointer". So you'll create a virtual path with begin path, draw the lines and finally stroke that lines. In next frame you'll begin a new virtual path, draw the new lines in the path and stroke again. This way the performance stays stable.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/nGygX/)

Comment: This was it exactly. Forgot about `beginPath()`. Thank you!